Sources some problems with the Series
I raised the difficulty of the problems on the study of series and I found techniques that are not seen in the standard exercises: for example, summation by parts (Abel's Lemma), and the "tauberian cut", use of complex numbers for the development of sine and cosine.
Do you have any sources to recommend to better master these techniques?
Example of use of "tauberian cut":
We must study the prove that $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{n}\sin(nk)$$ converges uniformly on $0$ if and only if $a_n=o(1/n)$ and is decreasing.
Now the estimation:
$$\sum_{i=m}^{n} a_{i} \sin(it) \leq \frac{2b_{n}}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}$$ doesn't work near $0$ (I don't understand why it is 100% true).
So we must use the "tauberian cut" for a better estimation:
$$
\sum_{i=m}^{n} a_{i} \sin(ik) \leq t\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p} k b_k + \frac{2 b_{n+p}}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} \leq tp + \left(\sup_{k \geq n} k b_k\right) + \frac{2 \pi b_{n+p}}{t}$$ 
because $$\frac{1}{\sin(kx)} \leq \frac{\pi}{x}$$

What is "decoupe taubelienne"; can you give an example?

@Sahaj He/she must allude to tauberian techniques with an "r" instead of an "l"

Yes. @JeanMarie

@Sahaj Of course

$$\frac{1}{\sin(kx)} \leq \frac{\pi}{t}$$ shuld be $$\frac{1}{\sin(kx)} \leq \frac{\pi}{x}$$
